# Re-create postgresql database to do pytest

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am working on a proyect that works with these libraries (among others)

```py
postgresql                10.5
pandas                    1.1.1
psycopg2                  2.7.5
pytest                    5.0.1
python                    3.7.1
```

I am trying to run pytest on a library we have created that uses sqlalchemy to access a postgresql database.

**I want to re-create a database to test the methods that we have being using for few months.**
I have tried different things but without success.

I know that postgresql cannot create an in memory database, which is why I am trying to use `sqlite3` for that purpose. .

The method I am trying to run test over is:

#### DatabaseHelper.py

```py
class DatabaseHelper(object):
    """
    Helps accessing database. 
    """

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    # ... 
        def create_engine(self, host_dns, dbname, port, user, password):
        """

        :param host_dns: dns route to the database
        :param dbname: name of the database to access to
        :param port: number or port of the database
        :param user: name of the user to access de database
        :param password: password to connect to the database
        """
        self.host = host_dns
        self.dbname = dbname
        self.port = port
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.connection_str = f'postgresql://{self.user}:{self.password}@{self.host}:{self.port}/{self.dbname}'
        self.engine = create_engine(self.connection_str)
        # session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)

        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session()
        # print("Agora objectec created ok")
    # ... 
    def read_db_to_df(self, **kwargs):  
        """ Reads a database and transforms into a pandas.DataFrame """
        try:
            default_reading_sql_args = {'con': self.session.connection()}
            reading_sql_args = utils.merge_two_dicts(default_reading_sql_args, kwargs)

            df = pd.read_sql(**reading_sql_args)
            return df
        except SQLAlchemyError as e:
            # self.logger.error("Error reading db to df")
            # self.logger.error(str(e).replace("\n", ""))
            print(e)
            return -20
```

#### MY_test_before_test.py

```py
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Column, Table, ForeignKey, select, PrimaryKeyConstraint, Index
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable, DropTable
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api import DeclarativeMeta
from agora_db.agora_helper import AgoraHelper
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import current_timestamp, current_user


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

Base = declarative_base()

#This is how the database models look like:

class Schema(object):
    """ A simple schema to provide a common argument for all tables """
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "ifsmtd"}


class AbstractTable(object):
    """
     A class that sets how the class is represents its objects as string.
    """

    def __repr__(self):
        """ Returns the object representation in string fromat in a way that can be used to reconstruct the object.

        This returns an 'official' string representation of the object.

        :Example:
        """
        from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect
        table_inst = inspect(self)
        table_name = type(self).__name__
        column_key_value = [(c_attr.key, getattr(self, c_attr.key)) for c_attr in table_inst.mapper.column_attrs]
        fields_str = ", ".join(["%s='%s'" % (c[0], c[1]) for c in column_key_value])
        return "<" + table_name + "(" + fields_str + ")>"

class MyBasicTable(Base, Schema, AbstractTable):
    __tablename__ = "mybasic_table"

    timest_mov = Column(TIMESTAMP, primary_key=True, nullable=False, server_default=current_timestamp())
    id_info = Column(String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    id_wf = Column(String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    process_name = Column(String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    error_type = Column(String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    resolution_status = Column(Boolean)
    aud_timest_umo = Column(TIMESTAMP, server_default=current_timestamp())
    aud_id_user = Column(String, server_default=current_user())
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('timest_mov', 'id_info', 'id_wf', 'process_name', 'error_type', name='pk_idx_mybasic_table'),
        Index('pk_idx_mybasic_table', 'timest_mov', 'id_info', 'id_wf', 'process_name', 'error_type', unique=True),
        {"schema": "ifsmtd"}
    )



dbhelper = DatabaseHelper()
dbhelper.engine = engine
dbhelper.session = session

query = session.query(MyBasicTable.timest_mov.label("timest_mov"),
                      MyBasicTable.id_info .label("id_info "),
                                                 MyBasicTable.id_wf.label("id_wf"),
                                                 MyBasicTable.process_name.label("process_name"),
                                                 MyBasicTable.error_type.label("error_type"),
                                                 MyBasicTable.resolution_status.label("resolution_status")
                                                 )\
                .distinct(MyBasicTable.id_jira.label("id_jira"))
df = dbhelper.read_db_to_df(sql=query.statement)
print(df)
```

#### The Error I get is:

> (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: ifsmtd.mybasic_table

How could I do the test.

Comment: I would strongly recommend *against* testing with one sort of database (SQLite) and using another in production (Postgres). It's convenient, but SQL databases are very quirky and your tests will be unrealistic. Postgres is free and its easy enough to run on your dev and test servers. Your tests and production should use the same SQLalchemy code to create databases and tables.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. If this was something I could choose I would use the environment for development but I am afraid that is nos possible at this time.

Comment: Definitely try out pytest-postgresql. It's a little bit complicated, but not too bad

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, there seems to be missing a call to Base.metadata.create_all(engine). This would create the initial database schema. After this call the tables are empty and you need to populate them.

Add the above statement just before using the database, but after defining the tables.

```
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)  # This will create the schema!
dbhelper = DatabaseHelper()
```

On the use of sqlite: I have also gone that route and bumped into the fact that by default sqlite does not check foreign key constraints (it can be enabled!). There may be more differences!